# What shuttlecraft is used in SNW Season 2, Episode 4? I think the Cervantes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-strange-new-worlds

In episode 4 (season 2), they fly in a shuttle craft down to the planet.  In one shot, there is a name written on the front of the shuttle- I think it is the Cervantes?  I can’t quite make it out, and in the only other frontal view, there is nothing written on the front.

Answer (score 1):

On this page:

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Among_the_Lotus_Eaters_(episode)

Cervantes is the only shuttle craft listed in the references, along with other craft and details that are used in that episode. If any other shuttlecraft were used, say Galileo, it would have listed it. So from this, I would say it was Cervantes.

https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cervantes

> The Cervantes (NCC-1701/5) was a Stamets-type Federation shuttlecraft in service to Starfleet in the 23rd century.

All other articles I have read just refer to a shuttlecraft.

Other note:

https://twitter.com/Pixomondo/status/1542533366976741378

Shows VFX company Pixomondo having two shuttlecraft in the Virtual Production studio, one of which has Galileo written on the side.

[image]

(Possibly) Cervantes from concept artwork.